# Symony: Unknown Entity namespace alias while working with 2 entity managers

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine

I am trying to work with 2 DBs and then 2 entity managers.
Here is my config doctrine part:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: g2s
        connections:
            main:
                driver: pdo_mysql
                host: '%database_host%'
                port: '%database_port%'
                dbname: '%database_name%'
                user: '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset: UTF8
            api:
                driver: pdo_mysql
                host: '%database_host%'
                port: '%database_port%'
                dbname: api
                user: '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset: UTF8
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: main
                auto_mapping: true
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            api:
                connection: api
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                mappings:
                    ApiBundle: ~
```

I ran the command "config:dump-reference" and the bundle is mapped.
But when trying to browse any page I got this error:
Unknown Entity namespace alias 'ApiBundle'

Comment: I never had much luck using automapping with multiple entity managers.

Answer (score 0):

According to docs, the proper way is to explicitly set all mappings, and this is what I do in my project as well. https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

There was a thread about this issue, and it should work for Symfony 2.6+ but same as @Cerad, I had no luck in enabling this. https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/60